# How does Flutter application get a barcode from the handheld barcode scanner?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, barcode, barcode-scanner

I need to read a barcode for a flutter application by using a **handheld barcode scanner**.
After pressing the trigger, the handheld barcode scanner reads the barcode and tries to send the value automatically to the input text that has focused.

[image]

Comment: You can do that with a Bluetooth connection scanner in keyboard input emulation mode.

Comment: Maybe not the answer you're looking for, but you can scan the barcode by your phone camera easily by a simple plugin https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanne Guess it's cheaper than buying a scanner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bare-code reader as an external keyboard over usb with your mobile or tablet .It will works fine .

[image]

Comment: That works very fine, thanks a lot. The handheld doesn't need an extra power supply?

Comment: For testing case you can plug the bar code reader directly with the OTG usb .But if you need to power the bar-code reader and the the phone at the same time there is some devices to ensure this function

Answer (score 4):

It depends which scanning device you are using.
In market there are various barcode scanner devices like scanbot, dynasoft, zebra scanner,etc. I would recommend you to use Zebra scanner.
Below is the link of zebra scanner home page where you can find the scanner devices and Android SDK and some sample demo codes
https://www.zebra.com/ap/en/support-downloads/scanners.html

If you are planning to integrate scanner with flutter application then you need to find plugin or write yourself a plugin

I have made a plugin for zebra barcode scanner. You can try this plugin [zebra_scanner_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/zebra_scanner_plugin)

I have tested it using the Zebra DS2278 model.

Answer (score 1):

Use this library [flutter_barcode_listener](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_barcode_listener)

It works like the following.

1. listen for physical keyboard raw key up event
2. filter out only 'REAL'
   characters (ASCII codes lower than 256, without special characters
   except enter)
3. on each new key check if previous key is older than
   bufferDuration, if it's older clear internal buffer
4. check if new key is enter key, if it is call onBarcodeScanned callback
   and clear buffer
5. if it's not enter key just append it to internal buffer;